# Convergence of a complex series, root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I got series
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{zn}{n+|z|}\right)^{n^2}$ and I'm trying to test its convergence.
I have tried root test

$C=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\left(\frac{zn}{n+|z|}\right)^{n^2}\right|}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{|z|n}{n+|z|}\right)^{n}$

but I don't know how to calculate this limit and if it is the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log C=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}n\log\left(\frac{|z| n}{|z|+n}\right)$$
thus $C\to\infty$ for $|z|>1$ and $C\to 0$ for $|z|<1$

$C=\frac{1}{e}$ for $|z|=1$

So the series converges absolutely for $|z|\le 1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$